# Serialize Java List to JSON without field name

Tags: json, jackson

```
public class MyResponse {

    private List<Data> data;

    public static class Data {
        private long id;
        private String name;
    }
}
```

Using Jackson this gets serialized  to the following JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 115125,
            "name": "AAAY"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need instead is the JSON like this, i,e. omitting the wrapping `Data` class:

```
[
    {
        "id": 115125,
        "name": "AAAY"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) annotation on the `data` field:

```java
public class MyResponse {

    @JsonValue
    private List<Data> data;

    ...
}
```